# FTP Implicit SSL class - never connects - how to debug?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, curl

I am trying to connect to an FTP service which requires the user to connect via Implicit SSL. The details are working in CuteFTP so my credentials are 100%.

I am trying to use this class and the connection method below but it just times outs.

Class: https://gist.github.com/maxrice/4544344

```
<?php
include "../objects/shared/ftp-implicit-ssl-tls.php";

$FTP_Implicit_SSL = new FTP_Implicit_SSL("myuser", "mypass", "rapidata.sharefileftp.com", 990, "Organisations/Avid/RDS_Data",  true);
$FTP_Implicit_SSL->upload("text.txt", "text.txt");
?>
```

There is a simple text.txt file in the same directory as the script.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not upload file. cURL Error: [7] - Failed to connect to rapidata.sharefileftp.com port 990: Connection timed out
```

My web host reports the script should be able to connect and this is what they see:

> Last login: Wed Apr 29 16:14:57 2015 from 79.174.170.1
>
> root@server-1:~# telnet rapidata.sharefileftp.com 990
>
> Trying 54.194.108.219...
>
> Connected to rapidata.sharefileftp.com.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.
>
> Then eventually
>
> Connection closed by foreign host.

Pleaase - any ideas what is going on here or how to find out?

what about these settings in the class?

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $username . ':' . $password,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // don't verify SSL
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_FTP_SSL        => CURLFTPSSL_ALL, // require SSL For both control and data connections
    CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH     => CURLFTPAUTH_DEFAULT, // let cURL choose the FTP authentication method (either SSL or TLS)
    CURLOPT_UPLOAD         => true,
    CURLOPT_PORT           => $port,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 300,
);
```

Comment: Have you tried with ftp_ssl_connect?

Comment: Yes but ftp_ssl_connect() opens an explicit SSL-FTP connection to the specified host. I need an inexplicit connection.

Comment: Yes, but you can test if an explicit SSL connection works or if it is a PHP problem.

Comment: Are you launching the telnet connection from the machine which also runs the PHP code?

Comment: I'm not sure - shall I ask my guys are the host? We use Ubuntu so that should be possible right?

Comment: @RichardReiber - I've tried $ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect("rapidata.sharefileftp.com", 990); and it won't connect with that either. Is the server address OK? I always wonder if it needs ftp:// or similar!

Comment: From Rapidata: Note: For security, only encrypted FTPS transfers are permitted. Configure your FTP client to connect using 'Implicit SSL/TLS' mode over Port 990. To enable standard, non-encrypted FTP access to your account, contact an administrator.

Comment: Do you get any PHP error/warning? If not, please enable error reporting. A prefix like ftp:// is not required as you use a wrapper function for opening a stream. PHP does this automatically if you use ftp_ssl_connect().

Comment: @RichardReiber - Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. That's because $ftp_conn didn't get anything back I assume!

Comment: @JamesWilson: No, that is because the hostname is not reachable. Can you try it with the IP address?

Comment: My host made a firewall change and now it connects. But I get the following: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not upload file. cURL Error: [25] - Failed FTP upload: 550'  - is this a permission problem at the other end now?

Comment: Try to change connection mode. [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php)